# Splashscreen wrong since XCode 7

Tags: angularjs, gruntjs, xcode7, splash-screen, hybrid-mobile-app

I took over a project using AngularJS, Ionic and Bootstrap to create hybrid apps for mobile devices.

Prior to upgrade to XCode 7 all went well. I updated my HTML-, CSS- and JS-code in editor, ran `grunt run:ios` to create platform code and opened XCode. From there I built the .ipa-file without any issues (justwith some warnings, which could be ignored).

However since using XCode 7 (needed for iOS 8- and iOS 9-devices), the splascreen will be shown incorrectly. Meaning: Rotated with 90°.

Note #1: The splashscreen and the app have to be Landscape-only.

Note #2: When running `grunt run:android`, all is well on the Android-based device.

Any idea what to do in order to get the old correct state again?

Answer (score 0):

There is a known bug in the `cordova-plugin-splashscreen` plugin relating to your issue ( [Issue CB-10244](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-10244) ). Try to update this plugin to `cordova-plugin-splashscreen@3.1.0` by re-adding it:

```
cordova plugin rm cordova-plugin-splashscreen
cordova plugin add cordova-plugin-splashscreen
```

Comment: Thanks, Beat. However the bug you mentioned talks about iPhone 6. I can reproduce the issue with iPhone 5 too...

Comment: Yes of course, but at least you could give it a try, because your problem seems to be very similar to the mentioned bug.

Comment: Interesting: After the update the splashscreen shortly pops up wrongly in simulator and iPhone 5 itself, it then jumps to the right place - reproducable.

So it looks as if you had been right for 50% ;-). 

Any (further) idea about the still remaining problem?

Comment: Hard to tell, because either me nor you really know about the project settings (You mentioned you took it over)...Which cordova-ios version do you use (`cordova platform ls`)? Have you checked all splashscreen related settings?

Comment: The cordova-ios version is 3.9.2. All splashscreen related settings had been checked twice...

Comment: I am still targeting iOS 3.8.0 and all works well for me. Have you checked the properties in `XCode` as well? Sometimes `XCode` can break/alter your properties set before...

Comment: Correct me, if I am wrong, but when running `grunt run:ios` and seeing the problem right away in emulator, XCode ist not part of the story, right?