# Splash-screen rotation not woking in Landscape mode on iOS devices

Tags: angularjs, xcode7, splash-screen, hybrid-mobile-app, landscape-portrait

I took over a project using AngularJS, Ionic and Bootstrap to create hybrid apps for mobile devices.

Prior to upgrade to XCode 7 all went well. I updated my HTML-, CSS- and JS-code in editor, ran `grunt run:ios` to create platform code and opened XCode. From there I built the .ipa-file without any issues (just with some warnings, which could be ignored).

However since using XCode 7 (needed for iOS 8- and iOS 9-devices), the splascreen will be shown incorrectly. Meaning: In Portrait mode.

Note #1: The splash-screen and the app have to be Landscape-only.

Note #2: When running `grunt run:android`, all is well on the Android-based device.

Per [34919547](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919547/splashscreen-wrong-since-xcode-7) I updated the cordova-plugin-splashscreen plugin to version 3.1.0 as suggested herein. I also changed a reference, as the old version was hard-coded in a config-file.

Now first the splash-screen is shown by mistake in Portraid mode, then (after the defined timeout) in Landscape mode as it should. So things go a little bit better, but not by 100%.

How to get the splash-screen shown *entirely* in Landscape mode?

Comment: You say there is a defiend timeout before the spalsh screen goes into landscape mode. My first thought would be to go into the cordova-plugin and change the timeout.

Answer (score 0):

Did you try cancelling out this line of code?

```
{
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Class class = [self class];

        SEL originalSelector = @selector(shouldAutorotate);
        SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(splash_shouldAutorotate);

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

        BOOL didAddMethod = class_addMethod(class,
                                            originalSelector,
                                            method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                                            method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(class,
                                swizzledSelector,
                                method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                                method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
    });
}
```

Try cancel it out like this:

```
{
    /*
    static dispatch_once_t onceToken;
    dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
        Class class = [self class];

        SEL originalSelector = @selector(shouldAutorotate);
        SEL swizzledSelector = @selector(splash_shouldAutorotate);

        Method originalMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, originalSelector);
        Method swizzledMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(class, swizzledSelector);

        BOOL didAddMethod = class_addMethod(class,
                                            originalSelector,
                                            method_getImplementation(swizzledMethod),
                                            method_getTypeEncoding(swizzledMethod));

        if (didAddMethod) {
            class_replaceMethod(class,
                                swizzledSelector,
                                method_getImplementation(originalMethod),
                                method_getTypeEncoding(originalMethod));
        } else {
            method_exchangeImplementations(originalMethod, swizzledMethod);
        }
    });
    */
}
```

You can find it in: `cordova-plugin-splashscreen/src/ios/CDVViewController+SplashScreen.m`

Comment: Strange: There is no such folder called ios at this point existing. Other ones like android, browser or ubuntu or there. 

Any (further) idea? I am honestly confused now...

Comment: ok well you should have this folder otherwise your plugin is probably incomplete. How did you install the plugin?

Comment: I fixed the issue with the missing /ios folder by restoring the relevant files from backup (not sure though, why they had been deleted, but anyways...). 

However the provided solution of commenting out the code does not work: Same situation as before.

Comment: Why do you need a plugin to create a splash screen? Can't you just code it in of use some other alternative like: http://www.appcoda.com/how-to-add-splash-screen-in-your-ios-app/

Comment: As written in the beginning: I took this project over, therefore I cannot answer your question by 100%, but I am pretty sure it has to do with the fact that this is a hybrid app. Meaning: It has to work on iOS AND Android devices ;-).

Comment: Did you check to see if the folder copy you have is the same as the original? Maybe you're missing some other important files or folders?

Comment: The files in the folder copy are the same.

Comment: I believe, I have found the original root cause of the problem: It seems to do with iOS 9.2. Running the code in XCode simulator with iOS is showing graphics right away correctly in Landscape mode.

Comment: Which version iOS are you running in XCode simulator? You do know you can download different versions of iOS in XCode sim? I would go ahead and test on all the latest iOS versions in XCode sim and see which ones have the loading issue. Curious to hear your answer.

Comment: Sorry, I have forgot to tell. With iOS 8.4 it works as expected. So it looks like an issue with iOS 9.x (9.2).

Comment: Yes, it seems there is little you can do to change that but work for Apple. I would report the bug immediately. Then again, maybe a small tweak to XCode source code would suffice but by the direction of our conversation till now, I have my doubts.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah - this is what I already did (opened a bug report with Apple). I am curious they will take it ;-).

Comment: And how did it go? Did you get an answer?

Comment: Actually I cancelled the bug with Apple (just 2 free per year) as the "solution" was to upgrade to cordova-ios 4.0.1 (better: 4.2.0-dev), which I figured out later on. Unfortunately another problem will take place then - the app crashes. It looks as if v 4.x is not stable though...

Comment: yep, still worth reporting though if you ask me (or would like a stable build)