# Splashscreen orientation wrong since iOS 9.x

Tags: ios-simulator, orientation, splash-screen, screen-orientation, ios9.2

As described in [34942234](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34942234/splash-screen-rotation-not-woking-in-landscape-mode-on-ios-devices) and [34919547](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34919547/splashscreen-wrong-since-xcode-7) I am fighting with a wrong splashscreen orientation since longer.

I am pretty sure I have nailed down the root cause, which has to do with iOS 9.x (I am using iOS 9.2). When running the identical code in XCode/iOS simulator with iOS 8.4 the splashscreen is shown in Landscape orientation as expected.

Testing the entire project as .ipa-file on my iPhone 5 with iOS 9.2 provides the same problem (unfortunately I have no device with ioS 8.x installed).

My questions are: What to do next? In case of opening a support ticket with Apple - will it be free of charge in case it turns out to be a bug (which is my educated guess)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have opened a bug report with Apple now; will see what their answer is...